# UITableView shows extra blank space

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, whitespace

UITableView shows extra blank space on the left, after I inserted array of parsed data. So, my question is how to trim whitespace in the tableView. I guess I have the blank space because of href hyperlink to the text I parsed which is shown as blank in the cell.

This is the part of HTML I parsed:

```
 <h3 style="clear:left"><a class="c4" href="http://www.website.ge/article-22624.html">
         Facebook - the text I have parsed </a></h3>
```

This is the code I used:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    NSError *error = nil;
    NSURL *url=[[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"http://www.website.ge/news"];
    NSString *strin=[[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];

    HTMLParser *parser = [[HTMLParser alloc] initWithString:strin error:&error];

    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
        return;
    }

    listData =[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];


    HTMLNode *bodyNode = [parser body];
    NSArray *dateNodes = [bodyNode findChildTags:@"span"];


    for (HTMLNode *inputNode in dateNodes) {
        if ([[inputNode getAttributeNamed:@"class"] isEqualToString:@"date"]) {
            //NSLog(@"%@", [inputNode contents]); 
            //[listData addObject:[inputNode contents]];
        }
    }    

    NSArray *divNodes = [bodyNode findChildrenOfClass:@"c4"];

    for (HTMLNode *inputNode in divNodes) {


           [listData addObject:[inputNode contents]];

            }

}
```

In the table view I see blank space at the beginning of the parsed data. It must be the hyperlink which is translated into blank space.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    //here you check for PreCreated cell.
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    //Fill the cells...  
    cell.textLabel.textAlignment=UITextAlignmentLeft; // attempt to move it to the left

    cell.textLabel.text = [listData objectAtIndex: indexPath.row];
    //yourMutableArray is Array 
    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming, based on your description, that you have extra whitespace in the text which you are displaying in a label.

If this is the case, take the string that you have created, and before setting the label use this:

```
theStringToDisplay = [theStringToDisplay stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
theLabel.text      = theStringToDisplay;
```

**EDIT now that you have supplied your code:**
In your case, I would use `stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet` when you are first setting the strings in your array:

```
NSArray *divNodes = [bodyNode findChildrenOfClass:@"c4"];
for (HTMLNode *inputNode in divNodes) {
    [listData addObject:[[inputNode contents] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]]];
}
```

Comment: How shall I apply this method to an array?

Comment: It looks what I need but it says whitespaceCharacterSet is undeclared identifier.

Comment: That's a class method so you need [NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]

Comment: What's not working? Do you still have the same problem you started with, or are you getting an error?

Comment: I don't have an error but the whitespace is still there. So, I have the same problem...

Comment: You meant doing this right? [listData addObject:[[inputNode contents] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]]];

Comment: Well, then it must not be a problem with whitespace at the beginning of the string.  Is your label too far to the right, so that it doesn't start at the beginning of the cell?

Comment: When I parsed the string which doesn't have hyperlink then there is no white space. So, it is the hyper link that messes with the text.

Comment: Try using `whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet` instead of `whitespaceCharacterSet`